# Laptop keyboard defective after updating Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: keyboard

After the latest Ubuntu 14.04 update, my laptop's keyboard started acting funny.

The rightmost letters are typing numbers instead, for example, `I` prints '5' and `K` prints '2'.

The strange thing is that when I connect a wireless keyboard it works great.
I thought it was a hardware defect, but when I used a live USB to start Ubuntu, the laptop keyboard worked OK.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem through *Ubuntu Forums*, and it was simple.

The `Num Lock` was activated, though I don't know how or why. I switched it off by holding down the `Fn` key (the one with only blue writing) then pressing `F11` (labelled NumLk in blue).